# What's behind GCP `There was an error while loading xxx. Please try again.` UI error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When accessing Google Cloud Platform Services, I'm requested to retry due to an unknown error. ****It affects all services I want to access.****

The snapshot below showcases the issue with Google Cloud Build.

[image: no access to Google Cloud Build dashboard]

Here's the same error with Google Cloud Storage.

[image: no access to Google Cloud Storage dashboard]

This has first occurred month ago but been automagically resolved without any further action from my side. This second appearance has now lasted  4 days.

Looking at [Google Cloud Status](https://status.cloud.google.com/summary), I can't link any incident to this behaviour.

Options I've been exploring with no success are:

1. Logging back in
2. Checking credential access

Important notes:

1. I have access to the global project dashboard: `https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=<project-name>`
2. Other teammates  do not face this. I'm now left with a few further actions since I access have been verified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried disabling all the browser extensions. Before narrowing it down to find that the Apollo Client DevTools extension was the culprit.

Comment: Wow what a crazy interaction. Had the same problem and it was driving me crazy, was using incognito mode to get around the issue. Seems disabling the Apollo extension has solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error resolved disabling "Keepa - Amazon Price Tracker" extension.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. It was because of `Popup Blocker Pro` for me.